# Measuring length of a circuit by signal attenuation (or of the like)

Tags: arduino, resistance

I'm pretty bad with electricity, so this might just be an ameture question, but here's my situation.

I'm wondering if I can, with any sort of accuracy, measure the length of a circuit using only the signal's information, and knowing what materials it's made of.

For example:[image]

What would I need to do to measure the resistance of aluminum over distance x, thus sampling the distance?

Again, I'm bad with this sort of thing, so use small words and link resources please.

Comment: Is the drawing you supplied *exactly* what you need to solve, or just an example? The answer is, yes, that is possible; but: it's not going to be the circle that you drew, but a much less nice shape that you know you're on, and the conditions to achieve that would be that you know the contact resistance to a very high degree, and that's going to be hard to achieve.

Comment: how are you expecting to measure the 3/4 of the circle that falls outside the metal plate?

Comment: There used to be a carbon loaded paper with usefully measurable (fairly low) conductivity. Model your design by cutting it out of that paper, measure what you need, and scale it to aluminium in a spreadsheet. Any Bob Pease fans remember what it's called?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Alu: ~ 3.5e7 S/m; carbon loaded paper, wild guess: 100 S/m; that will be an interesting experiment in scaling :)

Comment: I'm not planning on measuring the circle off the plate, but rather rapidly sampling the distance from 2 adjacent corners to find the location of the point on the plate. Also, is the carbon paper still around? Or is there a substitute that I could use instead?

Comment: @BrianDrummond **Teledeltos  paper**. Been awhile, but that long-term memory still holds ;-)

Comment: Wow! Yes and yes. That's the stuff - from Uncle Bob himself http://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/whats-all-teledeltos-stuff-anyway and it's still available! http://www.betterequipped.co.uk/teledeltos-conductive-paper-prd1516-pack-of-10-sheetsp-1262

Comment: And Hackaday's take on it... https://hackaday.com/2015/09/28/the-conductive-paper-that-sparked-a-revolution/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not like you imagine it would work:

What you could measure is the *effective resistance* from your corner to your contact point. That's probably what you've meant with attenuation.

That resistance is going to be very, very small. You need a very sensitive (read: expensive) measurement device to measure it. An Arduino cannot do this on its own.

The resistance of the contacts will be hard to determine. So, they add *uncertainty* to your problem. Sadly, that uncertainty will be much larger than the measurable resistance, so, this will also not work out.

Now, you will quickly notice that if you put your contact pen on a place on the edge of your metal plane, then the current between the pen and the other contact has much less area to flow through then when you put it somewhere in the middle of the plane.

This idea alone shows that the "points of identical resistance" will not be on a circle; the shape of your metal plane plays an important role here!

So, what is the shape of the "points of identical resistance"? That's hard to answer.

In fact, you will need to realize that the question "where does current flow in a large conductor" needs a consideration where current already flows – because where current flows throug a non-perfect conductor, there is a voltage (potential difference), as well as a magnetic field (induction!). That magnetic field will "push away" other currents that produce a similar magnetic field. But then you get a different potential. And then you get different currents.

So, this leads to a system of equations where one equation depends on the integral of another equation. We call such equations *differential equations*.

The shape of the metal plane gives you *boundary conditions*. For example, there can't be current flowing "out of" the plate.

To solve such *systems of differential equations*, one can sometimes still find a closed form solution (i.e. a formula). But usually, that is impossible, and the best we can do is do a *simulation*. Such a simulation typically breaks down that plane into thousands of smaller planes, and then does what we call *finite elements methods* to simulate how things behave in total.

None of this is possible without a very fast computer and without very deep knowledge of how electrical and magnetic fields work.

I'm afraid the answer is:

> Yes, calculating possible places on your plane based on measuring the resistance is possible. It is not possible in any way that you think of, and it will take years of study to learn how its possible and very expensive equipment to do so.

Comment: Despite my not understanding electricity, I am quite good at math and I think I could work my way around the calculus. I might not be able to make it work in the end given what you've said, but I would like to look more into it. Could you link some sources for the differential equations you mentioned earlier? Also, thanks for such a speedy and thorough response.

Comment: In fact, these equations would be Maxwell's equations, and the boundary conditions would be no current perpendicular to the edges at the edges, the externally applied voltage as potential at the contacting points, and \$\frac d{dt} = 0\$, assuming stationarity (which implies zero curl, for example). Maxwell's  Eqs are covered in every book that has "electromagnetic" in its title, but also on wikipedia (and in many, many other places). They are among the most fundamental ways physicists describe the world (as long as we stay away from quantum or relativistic effects).

Comment: Will the plate really be aluminium? If so you have the additional problem that aluminium has a protected layer of oxide on top which you have to break through to make contact. Which will affect your contact area and thus resistance. You probably have to start with a very sharp pointed probe and a mechanical means to always use the same pressure.

Comment: Is there a durable, available metal that does not oxidize or have a similar problem? Otherwise, is the resistance of the oxide layer predictible assuming I have control over all other environment variables (pressure, penetration, surface area, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Standard copper foil (1 ounce/foot^2) is 1.4 mils thick and has 0.00050 ohms resistance per square. A 1mm wire soldered to the corner of 1.4mil foil will
dump current into the 3 squares adjacent to the 1mm wire: resistance will be 0.00050/3 = 170 microOhms. The next squares past that will have size 2mm per side, and another 170microOhm. The 3 layer os square have size  4mm, the 4rth layer of square have size 8mm, then 16mm, then 32 mm then 64mm (or 6.2cm, or about 2.5 inches).

Yet the total resiatance is 6 layers * 170 microOHms or 1,000 microohms or just 1 milliohm.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkoRqG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>